# Getting link attribute with different id`s

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking looking for a way to get the links for all currencies on [this website][1].

So I would like to get back:

```
/currencies/euro/
/currencies/usd/
etc.
```

I tried the following, which just gives me one link:

```
//*[@id="id-eur"]/td[2]/a
```

Any suggestions how to generalize this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `XPath` to get required output:

```
//table[@id="currencies"]//img[@class="currency-logo"]/following-sibling::a/@href
```